# Filter rows based on value in column

Tags: r

I want to filer the data frame to remove rows that occure with similar names in col0. I two or more similar names occur, I want to keep the row with highest values in col1.

```
col0              col1     col2      col3      col4          col4          col5
hsa-let-7a-5p   2.487304 15.04636  8.400422 1.702870e-10 1.084728e-07 13.867065
hsa-let-7a-5p   2.491626 13.70345  7.414093 4.002913e-09 1.274928e-06 10.808433
hsa-let-7d-5p   3.074776 11.36059  6.799401 2.977052e-08 6.321274e-06  8.887774
hsa-miR-7d-5p   3.123776 11.84145  6.210222 2.069015e-07 3.050719e-05  7.032421
hsa-miR-122-5p  -2.521427 13.91681 -6.132486 2.673240e-07 3.050719e-05  6.703794
hsa-miR-122-5p  2.602304 11.53867  6.083099 3.145797e-07 3.050719e-05  6.636385
```

In my example I want to keep row2,row4 and row6. 
Any tips on function?

Comment: Do u have a matrix?

Comment: data frame. sorry

Comment: data.frame cannot have duplicate row names

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: In base R, you could do `unique(dat[order(dat$col0, -dat$col1),])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it is a `data.frame`, then it cannot have duplicated row names.  So, either it must be a `matrix` or it could be the first column of `data.frame`.  By assuming that, grouped by the first column i.e. 'col0', `slice` the row with the maximum value in 'col1'

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
    group_by(col0) %>%
    slice(which.max(col1))
```